# External JavaScript Error

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

This is not new to me.  Including external JS files in the HTML is something I've done a million times.

However I have never seen an error like this and can't find the culprit.

In the header I have

```
<script type='text/JavaScript' src='psrChoices.js'></script>
```

In that file I have

```
function setIncidentStatusChoices(selectObj, selectedValue) {
    var values = getIncidentStatus(); 
    setChoicesAndSelected(selectObj, values, values, selectedValue);
}
```

In the .jsp Page I have

```
setIncidentStatusChoices(document.incidentPeopleAdd.statusOnIncident, "    <%=incidentPeople.getStatusOnIncident()%>");
```

It's telling me that the function is undefined.  I have thousands upon thousands of other external .js files that are usable.  I have scanned the choices file for errors and have found none.  I copied the function to the local page and it worked fine.

Do any of you have any ides of where to look for an error?

Comment: Well is the JS file being loaded?

Comment: Also I tried both language='JavaScript' (which is what i use normally) but changed it to text='blabla' just to see the diff

Comment: Use debugging tools to make sure that the file is being loaded...

Comment: I used FireBug which allowed me to see the Choices.js file.

Comment: Are you trying to call the function before the file is loaded? Is the function in the global scope?

Comment: The function initLists() calls functions from the file.  This function is called when the document is ready via jQuery

Comment: Just changed it to window.onload still not working.  ran the choices js file through an error finder and fixed what it found.  still not working.